# Connected UILabel error EXC_BAD_EXCEPTION when trying to change text value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

Something very strange has been happening when I change my UILabel's text in my view controller's viewDidLoad method. Although I am 100% certain that the label is connected (I have reconnected it multiple times as well as changed the name), it still gives me an EXC_BAD_EXCEPTION error when trying to change it. My code is below.

**NOTE: I should also mention that this error does not occur when the VC first initializes, but when I press a button that segues to another VC.

```
class BroadwayOrderReview: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ClassNameDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var BroadwayOrderReviewTableView: UITableView!


@IBOutlet weak var finalOrderPriceTotalLbl: UILabel!


var OrderDictionary: [String:String] = [:]



func addButtonAction(addedList:[String:Float],numOrders:[String:Int]) {
    print(addedList)
    print(numOrders)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("NUM ORDERS \(numOrders)")

    self.finalOrderPriceTotalLbl.text = "0.00"


    let totalPriceArray = Array(numOrders.keys).sort(<)
    for (key) in totalPriceArray {
        print("TOTAL PRICE ARRAY \(totalPriceArray)")
        self.finalOrderPriceTotalLbl.text = String(Float(self.finalOrderPriceTotalLbl.text!)! + (Float(numOrders[key]!) * addedList[key]!))
        print("TOTAL ORDER LBL \(finalOrderPriceTotalLbl.text)")
    }

    BroadwayOrderReviewTableView.delegate = self
    BroadwayOrderReviewTableView.dataSource = self

    for (name,orders) in numOrders {
        print(name)
        OrderDictionary["\(numOrders[name]!) \(name)"] = String(addedList[name]! * Float(numOrders[name]!))
    }
    print(OrderDictionary)
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the error xcode is giving me]

Thank you for any and all help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You might be certain its connected but what does Xcode's connection manager show for the connection/s ?

Comment: It means your label is nil.  Either because your outlet isn't connected properly or because you aren't instantiating your view controller correctly.

Comment: It is definitely connected, it shows up on the list of connections in the manager.

Comment: @dan I have played around with initializing this VC, but to no avail. Can you please point me in the right direction as to how I can properly initialize this VC? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried deleting derived data, cleaning the project, exiting Xcode and then re-lauching and re-building? When things involving a storyboard/connection etc. fail for no logical reason, then in my experience just exiting Xcode will solve them 95% of the time.

Comment: How are you instantiating BroadwayOrderReview? Through a segue?

Comment: @picciano yes, a button on another VC segues to this. I should also note that this error does not occur when the VC first initializes, but when I press another button that segeus to another VC. I know I am stupid for not including this in the initial question, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a capital for naming your tableView.
BroadwayOrderReviewTableView should be broadwayOrderReviewTableView. You only want to use class, struct with first letter caps.

Did you try to delete your label from your code and storyboard?
It looks like the connection isn't there.
With what you shared it seems it can't access a value because it hasn't been initialized.

Something i didn't know when I started learning dev. you can actually type in the console log.
type `po finalOrderPriceTotalLbl` (for print out finalOrderPriceTotalLbl)
You can only use that when your app is on standby with breakpoint, and maybe crashes (I forgot for one sec) to setup a breakpoint just click on the number's line. to remove just drag it out.
If the print give you nil. you know there is a issue with your label connection for sure.